Floating Point: Distance between MAX and INF
Let's say you have a variable of a floating point type. 32 or 64 bit doesn't matter.
You assign the maximum representable value to the variable. Typical programming languages have a constant for that.
How do you determine the least value that you must add to your variable so that it 'snaps' over to infinity?
I am aware of functions like nextafter* and nexttoward* in C, next_up in Rust, etc. Those are related, but do not give me the value that I need.

If the question is restricted to IEEE-754 binary floating-point arithmetic, please state that in the question. If IEEEE-754 only, are you asking with regard to a particular rounding mode, or do you expect an answer to cover all rounding modes specified by IEEE-754?

I do not have a restriction to IEEE-754 in mind, but since practically all relevant programming languages do FP arithmetic on basis of it, I think it's okay to focus on that.
Also, I do not have a particular rounding mode in mind, but an answer for any of the defined IEEE-754 rounding modes would add value. Ideal would be an answer that covers all of them of course.

Would something like this be an acceptable answer (ISO-C, IEEE-754 binary32, round-to-nearest-or-even): `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (void)
{
float x = FLT_MAX;
int expo = FLT_MAX_EXP - FLT_MANT_DIG - 1;
float y = ldexpf (1.0f, expo);
printf ("x=%15.6a y=%15.6a sum=%15.6a\n", x, y, x + y);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
`

Perhaps. Frankly, I don't know. I am not claiming that I understand what the program does. It's clear that the sum of FLT_MAX and y is inf, but I would need an explanation of the magic you're doing to arrive at y.

Do you mean this: https://godbolt.org/z/sd5GEfEG6 ? Note the difference between the exponents

@Bob__ Your program determines the value by iteration. That'll work of course. Thanks for pointing that out, I neglected to do so myself. I was wondering if there is an easier way to arrive at the value.

Re “You assign the maximum representable value to the variable”: If +∞ is representable, then it is the maximum representable value. You mean the maximum representable finite value.

Re “How do you determine…”: This is an ill-posed question. How do I determine the least value to add based on my knowledge of the format? How would I write code to calculate it from properties provided in the programming language, such as FLT_MANT_DIG in C? How would I write code to compute it via some iterative trial-and-error algorithm? Clarify the question as to what the purpose and situation is.

Here is a solution for float in C. It uses FLT_ROUNDS, which may be changed during program execution. If a program does that, this code should use #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON to inform the compiler it depends on the floating-point environment.
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    #if !defined INFINITY

        printf("Infinity is not representable, so no value added to %a can produce infinity.\n", FLT_MAX);

    #else

        /*  a will be set to the largest value that can be added that will
            not produce infinity, and b will be set to the smallest value that
            will produce infinity.
        */
        float a, b;

        switch (FLT_ROUNDS)
        {
            case  0:  // Toward zero.
            case  3:  // Downward, toward negative infinity.
            {
                //  With rounding downward or toward zero, no finite value will round to +infinity.
                a = FLT_MAX;
                b = INFINITY;
                break;
            }

            case  1:  // To nearest, ties to even.
            case  4:  // To nearest, ties away from zero.
            {
                //  Determine ULP at FLT_MAX;
                float u = FLT_MAX - nexttowardf(FLT_MAX, 0);

                //  The smallest value that will produce infinity is half an ULP.
                b = u/2;
                a = nexttowardf(b, 0);

                break;
            }

            case  2:  // Upward, toward positive infinity.
            {
                //  With rounding upward, adding any non-negative value will produce infinity.
                a = 0;
                b = FLT_TRUE_MIN;
                break;
            }

            case -1:  // Indeterminable, or, rather, the implementation will not tell us.
            {
                //  Check whether boundary is between FLT_MAX and INFINITY.
                if (FLT_MAX + FLT_MAX < INFINITY)
                {
                    /*  Adding FLT_MAX does not produce infinity, so infinity
                        is the smallest value that does.
                    */
                    a = FLT_MAX;
                    b = INFINITY;
                }

                else
                {
                    //  Otherwise, do a binary search.
                    a = 0;
                    b = FLT_MAX;
                    float middle;
                    while (nexttowardf(a, b) != b)
                    {
                        middle = (a + b) / 2;
                        if (FLT_MAX + middle < INFINITY)
                            a = middle;
                        else
                            b = middle;
                    };
                }

                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                printf("FLT_ROUNDS is %d, which does not conform to the C 2024 standard.\n", FLT_ROUNDS);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        printf("The smallest value that will produce infinity is %a.\n", b);
        printf("Demonstration:\n");
        printf("\t%a + %a = %a.\n", FLT_MAX, a, FLT_MAX + a);
        printf("\t%a + %a = %a.\n", FLT_MAX, b, FLT_MAX + b);

    #endif
}

